# ROWNUM with a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am wondering if a select statement or view can be achieve to have a running number based on a condition

`Col_1      Col_2   Col_3   Col_4   Col_5
20010887A   DISP    CT1     A030    K2772   1
20010887A   DISP    CT1     A040    K1444   2
20010887A   DISP    CT1     A050    K2422   3
20010887A   DISP    CT1     A060    K3430   4
20010887A   DISP    CT2     D115    K1473   1
20010887A   DISP    CT2     D120    K0053A  2
20010887A   DISP    CT2     D130    K1444   3
20010887A   MIX     CT1     F190    K1420   1
20010887A   MIX     CT2     F220    K1433   1
20010887A   MIX     CT3     G260    K2742A  1
20010887A   MIX     CT4     I310    K0916   1
20010887A   MIX     CT5     J330    K1258   1`

The last column is the running number I wanted and it was grouped using Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_5. Col_4 is just a sorting sequence.

> SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4, COL_5, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
>   PARTITION BY COL_1, COL_2, COL_3 ORDER BY COL_4) AS Col5_Count FROM
>   myTable

Using the above query, is it possible to have Col_3 ROW_NUMBER counted the same way but in a distinct manner ? For example, all CT1 should have 1, CT2 should have 2.

Thanks

Comment: Could you amend your question with an example of the outcome you are looking for?

Comment: You can easily achieve the output you are looking for using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col_1, Col_2, Col_3 ORDER BY Col_4)`

Comment: Hi Giorgos, thanks ! I am testing RANK(), ROW_NUMBER, DENSE_RANK but I completely missed out PARTITION BY. Once I added it, just works ... thanks.

Comment: SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4, COL_5, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY COL_1, COL_2, COL_3 ORDER BY COL_4) AS Col5_Count
  FROM myTable

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to have Col_3 `ROW_NUMBER` counted the same way but in a distinct manner ? For example, all `CT1` should have 1, `CT2` should have 2.

You can use the `DENSE_RANK()` analytic function:

```
SELECT t.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY COL_1, COL_2, COL_3 ORDER BY COL_4 ) AS Col5_Count,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY COL_3 ) AS Col3_Rank
FROM   myTable t
```